# getting string mix using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, text

```
import re
s = 'words here plus num A18-11186 B7  and Q12-45786 D3'
```

I have the following string and I want to extract `A18-11186 B7` and `Q12-45786 D3` using regular expressions. I have tried the following

```
reg = r'\b(?=\d*[A-Z])((?:[A-Z0-9]+-)(?:\d+-)?\d+)\b'
r1 = re.findall(reg,s)
```

Which gives me

```
['A18-11186', 'Q12-45786']
```

This is close to what I want except it is missing a space, letter, and digit.

How do I change my `reg` to get my desired output?

desired output

```
['A18-11186 B7', 'Q12-45786 D3']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get your matches without using a positive lookahead and use word boundaries `\b` before matching the first uppercase char and the last digit.

```
\b[A-Z][0-9]+-[0-9]+ [A-Z][0-9]+\b
```

In parts

- `\b` Word boundary
- `[A-Z][0-9]+` Match single A-Z and 1+ digits
- `-[0-9]+`  Match `-`, 1+ digits and a space
- `[A-Z][0-9]+` Match single A-Z and 1+ digits
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uCwqis/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Z4QtNo)

For example

```
import re
regex = r"\b[A-Z][0-9]+-[0-9]+ [A-Z][0-9]+\b"
test_str = "words here plus num A18-11186 B7  and Q12-45786 D3"
print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

Output

```
['A18-11186 B7', 'Q12-45786 D3']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure about the expected formatting then you can use:

```
[A-Z0-9-]+[A-Z0-9 -]*?[A-Z0-9-]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/LMvz15/1